# Login pass through from legacy sites to Laravel site

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, encryption, single-sign-on

I have a lot of legacy sites written mainly in CodeIgniter. I was to be able to issue something to those sites that says they have access to a new Laravel site.

My plan is to create one account on the Laravel site for each legacy site. Anyone that can login to the legacy site can click a link to navigate and be logged into the Laravel site with the associated account.

What would be the best way of handling this? I was thinking about creating an encrypted string made in the Laravel site and store it in the configuration of the legacy sites. The legacy site would then just pass that back to the Laravel site and it gets decrypted. Would this be secure? Should there be some kind of encryption/decryption on both ends?

Comment: If the codeigniter sites used bcrypt to hash passwords, you could just copy their accounts along with hashes and Laravel's `Auth` should work.

Comment: They do not use bcrypt and I don't want every account from the site in the Laravel site. Essentially, any account on the CodeIgniter site will pass through to a global account for that site on the Laravel site.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best idea to store permanent log in links in a legacy site - or any site for that matter. A more secure approach would be to set up an authenticated API endpoint on the Laravel site that takes the user's info when they click the link on your legacy site, then creates their account and emails a confirmation as a second step. The flow would look something like this:

1. User clicks link on legacy site
2. Legacy site makes an authenticated request to the Laravel API endpoint with the legacy user's info (email, username, etc)
3. Laravel emails the user a link which expires in x amount of time to complete the registration process
4. User follows the link to your new Laravel site, where they add a password and account details, then confirm their account creation.

A nice additional feature would be to then update your legacy site to say the user has created their account in the new site. That way if the user logs in to the legacy site, you can remind them that the new version is available for use, or just force redirect them.

Comment: The Laravel site will act essentially as an addon to the old sites. If the site decides they want to have access to the Laravel site, I will manually go and create an account on the Laravel site that links to the old site. This way, any user on the old site can access the Laravel site by using a link on the old site.